# PySide 2 installed successfully but not Shiboken 2

Tags: python, qt, pyside, python-module

I have successfully managed to build and install `PySide2` on **Python 3.6.4.** (default, not Anaconda) on **Windows 10** operating system.

However `shiboken2` has not been installed. How may I install `shiboken2`? I know that that the code for this module is attached to `PySide2` installation files.

I suspect that my **C++** code which is built as **DLL** file cannot be imported in Python due to missing `shiboken2`. However this importing works fine in **Anaconda** environment. But at the moment I do not want to use **Anaconda** because there are old versions of 'Qt' (`5.6` but I need `5.9.x`) and 'PySide2' installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a moment ago I figured it out that `shiboken2` can be imported like this:

```
    from PySide2 import shiboken2
```

So before importing my own files the above line has to be added.